# Access nth value of Array in Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

I would like to access the second value of an array in Nunjucks. Is this possible? I've read through the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html) but I can't seem to work it out.

`{{ array | first }}` and `{{ array | last }}` work, but is it possible to do something like `{{ array | second }}` ?

Comment: `{{array[1]}}`?

Comment: that works, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just to solidify Aikon Mogwai's comment, you can do this with bracket notation on the array itself like this:

```js
var data = { arr: ['a','b','c'] }
var templateStr = "{{ arr[1] }}"
var result = nunjucks.renderString(templateStr, data) // 'b'
```

#### [Demo in CodePen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/embed/GRQygOE?default-tab=js%2Cresult)